# How do I install ffmpeg on CentOS 6.8 with all dependencies? I am getting many "Error package ... requires ..."

Tags: centos, software-installation, ffmpeg, shared-library

I am trying to install ffmpeg on a CentOS 6.8 server and I am getting some errors relating to required libs. How do I install those missing libs? Where do I find them? What should I do to install FFMPEG?

**Here are the errors:**

```
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-compat-0.6.7-9.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libjack.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: xvidcore-1.3.2-5.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopus.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1(CDIO_CDDA_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-compat-0.6.7-9.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.4-2.20131205.gitdc76f0a.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_12)(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.4-2.20131205.gitdc76f0a.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenjpeg.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-compat-0.6.7-9.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libopenjpeg.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1(CDIO_PARANOIA_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: x265-libs-1.9-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_0_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.4-2.20131205.gitdc76f0a.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**RepoList:**

```
200 packages excluded due to repository protections
repo id            repo name                                           status
base               CentOS-6 - Base                                      6,634+62
dag                DAG RPM Repository                                   4,634+84
extras             CentOS-6 - Extras                                          61
hgdedi             HG Monitoring Repo                                        369
ksplice-uptrack    Ksplice Uptrack for CentOS                                 14
nodesource         Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           49
nux-dextop         Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use                 2,347+123
rpmforge           RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                          4,634+84
ul                 UL                                                         58
ul_hostgator       UL_HostGator                                                8
updates            CentOS-6 - Updates                                        137
repolist: 18,945
```

Comment: Did you try both suggestions at the end of the errored `yum` command?

Comment: I have tried both of the suggestions but doesn't install ffmpeg

Comment: What does it do when you `yum install --skip-broken ffmpeg`?

Comment: it skips packages and ffmpeg doesn't get installed.

Comment: Big mistake : Seems you are trying to use CentOS **7** packages / a CentOS **7** repo for CentOS 6.8, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have been using both DAG and NUX repos. NUX repos are more updated, so when yum looks for dependencies it gives those for CentOS 7, I'm sure that is the reason dependencies do not get installed.

If you disable NUX for a moment, and only use DAG for this purpose, I think the instructions mentioned here would work fine. I have tried them in CentOS 6 myself. https://chrisjean.com/install-ffmpeg-and-ffmpeg-php-on-centos-easily/

I hope that works for you.

Comment: It appears that the DAG yum mirror from that link is no longer active. Will search for another one and once I find it, will post it here.